# Sign in to twitter via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, twitter

I'm experimenting with PowerShell and got following problem:

When I wanted to sign in to twitter using Invoke-WebRequest

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.twitter.com"
$r.Forms[1].Fields.session[username_or_email] = "user"
$r.Forms[1].Fields.session[password] = "password"
```

and tried to assign a value to request object, it was impossible because of the twitter naming convention of their fields. This is what I got as an error message

> Unexpected token 'username_or_email]' in expression or statement.

Is there some simple way to escape this characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the field is `session[username_or_email]` and in PowerShell you have two ways of referring to that:

```psh
# dot notation, but it must be quoted because of special characters
$r[1].Fields."session[username_or_email]"

# array notation, must be quoted either way
$r[1].Fields["session[username_or_email]"]
```

Normally you could have just done `$r[1].Fields.TheFieldName` but you have to put it in quotes because of the special characters involved.

Additionally, I will point out that the response in `$r` should have already parsed all the fields into the object, letting you tab complete them, but this object does a strange thing: if an `<input>` field has an `id` attribute, it will name the object based on that instead of the name, which is why you'll find a field called `signin-email` but not one already named `session[username_or_email]`.

If it causes you issues when you submit, you may want to manually remove the id-based fields.

Comment: By manually removing the id named form fields, do you mean `$r.Forms[1].Fields.Remove('signin-email')`?

Comment: Thanks, I taught that because of ps intellisense, I could not use quotes. Silly me :)

Comment: Intellisense is how I first figured out that quotes worked with dot notation!

Comment: If we submit after adding the fields to form, error seems to be "Server accepted the request but refused to serve the request" like that. Any idea about that? Is it because of not setting the header property while initiating webrequest?